# Creat new Trigger in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have this TRIGGER in mysql database  but I have error 
this is my TRIGGER CODE

```
CREATE TRIGGER `chk_mac_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `radacct`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  # Check if user mac is already added in radcheck table,
 SET @mac = (SELECT count(*) from radcheck where username=New.username and 
 attribute='Calling-Station-ID');
# If there is no entry for mac, then update mac in radcheck table, so that 
in future only this mac will be able to connect with that username
IF (@mac = 0) THEN 
INSERT into radcheck (username,attribute,op,value) values 
(NEW.username,'Calling-Station-ID',':=',NEW.callingstationid); 
# add mac in users table for general record purpose
 UPDATE users SET mac = NEW.callingstationid where username = NEW.username;
  # trim mac for first 3 strings to detect vendor company
 SET @mactrim = (select LEFT(mac, 8) from users where 
 username=New.username);
# get vendor name from mac db table
SET @macvendor1 = (select vendor from macdb where oui=@mactrim);
# Update vendor name in user table
UPDATE users SET macvendor=@macvendor1 where username = NEW.username;
END IF;
END
```

but I have this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

Comment: Did you use DELIMITER?

Comment: I am not sure but try to use "NEW" instead of "New"...........  where username=NEW.username

Comment: No I don't use DELIMITER

Comment: thank you for your reply but not working  @Mittal

Comment: Same error at line 3???

Comment: yes same error in same line @Mittal

Comment: It may be due to comment.When you use "#" for comment (# This comment continues to the end of line) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html ... Change the # with "-- "

Comment: Raymond meant: "Did you use delimiter? And if not, use it, because you need it." See e.g. [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html) (or every working example for a trigger or stored procedure that has more than 1 statement in the body).

Comment: For your @mac variable assignment, have you tried.. SELECT count(*) into mac from your table where condition etc.. you also may need to declare that variable prior to assigning it a value like..DECLARE mac integer.